# highcharts not showing in internet explorer

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts an it is not showing in IE but well in chrome. I have created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/starcraft04/px6dmvnx/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            loading: 'Loading...',
            months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
            weekdays: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
            shortMonths: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            exportButtonTitle: 'Export',
            printButtonTitle: 'Print',
            rangeSelectorFrom: 'From',
            rangeSelectorTo: 'To',
            rangeSelectorZoom: 'Zoom',
            downloadPNG: 'Download PNG',
            downloadJPEG: 'Download JPEG',
            downloadPDF: 'Download PDF',
            downloadSVG: 'Download SVG',
            resetZoom: 'Reset',
            resetZoomTitle: 'Reset',
            thousandsSep: '',
            decimalPoint: ','
        },
        chart: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: true,
            plotBorderWidth: 1
        }
    });

    var options = {};
    options.series = [];
    options.xAxis = [];
    options.yAxis = [];
    options.chart = {
        zoomType: 'x',
        renderTo: 'graph',
        marginRight: 50,
        marginBottom: 50
    };
    options.title = {
        text: 'My Graph',
        x: -20 //center
    };
    options.subtitle = {
        text: 'Test',
        x: -20
    };
    options.legend = {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -10,
        y: 18,
        borderWidth: 0
    };
    options.tooltip = {
        shared: false,
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 1
    }


    options.xAxis[0] = {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickWidth: 1,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        gridLineColor: '#cdcdcd',
        tickPixelInterval: 70,
        opposite: false
    };
    options.yAxis[0] = {
        tickWidth: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        gridLineColor: '#cdcdcd',
        tickPixelInterval: 100,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value;
            },
            style: {
                color: '#0080c0'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'test',
            style: {
                color: '#0080c0'
            }
        },
        opposite: false
    };
    options.series[0] = {
        name: 'test',
        color: '#0080c0',
        xAxis: 0,
        yAxis: 0,
        type: 'spline',
        data: [
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 00:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42121000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42156000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 02:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42186000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 03:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42213000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 04:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42243000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 05:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42269000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 06:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42297000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 07:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42323000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42346000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 09:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42374000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 10:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42404000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 11:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42439000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 12:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42539000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 13:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42585000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 14:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42626000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 15:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42672000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 16:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42707000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 17:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42733000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42755000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 19:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42779000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 20:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42802000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 21:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42832000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 22:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42871000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 23:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42916000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 00:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42952000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42988000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 02:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('43015000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 03:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('43041000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 04:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('43069000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 05:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('43096000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('43124000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 07:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('43149000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 08:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('43176000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 09:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('43321000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 10:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('43552000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 11:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('43783000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 12:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('44014000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 13:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('44248000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 14:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('44479000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 15:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('44710000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 16:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('44939000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 17:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('45168000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('45398000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 19:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('45630000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 20:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('45863000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 21:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('46099000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 22:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('46353000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 23:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('46464000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 00:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('46516000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('46560000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 02:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('46592000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 03:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('46620000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 04:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('46647000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 05:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('46674000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('46701000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 07:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('46726000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 08:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('46765000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 09:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('46889000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 10:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('47122000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 11:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('47366000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 12:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('47625000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 13:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('47880000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 14:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('48123000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 15:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('48377000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 16:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('48621000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 17:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('48862000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('49087000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 19:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('49324000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 20:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('49555000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 21:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('49792000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 22:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('50038000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 23:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50145000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 00:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50186000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50222000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 02:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50250000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 03:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50275000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 04:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50302000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 05:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50326000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50355000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 07:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50380000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50406000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 09:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50544000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 10:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50774000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 11:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('51002000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 12:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('51232000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 13:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('51466000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 14:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('51546000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 15:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('51587000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 16:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('51642000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 17:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('51780000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('52038000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 19:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('52292000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 20:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('52529000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 21:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('52772000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 22:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53016000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 23:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53078000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 00:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53114000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53148000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 02:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53176000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 03:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53203000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 04:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('53229000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 05:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53255000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53283000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 07:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53309000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53342000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 09:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53486000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 10:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53714000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 11:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('53944000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 12:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('54173000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 13:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('54403000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 14:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('54633000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 15:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('54863000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 16:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('55094000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 17:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('55323000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 18:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('55553000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 19:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('55782000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 20:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('56018000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 21:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56265000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 22:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56522000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 23:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56635000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 00:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('56685000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56729000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 02:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56766000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 03:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56799000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 04:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56833000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 05:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('56866000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56902000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 07:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56935000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56964000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 09:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('57107000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 10:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('57337000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 11:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('57581000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 12:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('57824000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 13:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('58063000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 14:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('58308000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 15:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('58547000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 16:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('58787000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 17:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('59020000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('59247000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 19:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('59491000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 20:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('59744000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 21:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('59825000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 22:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('59902000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 23:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('59984000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 00:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60063000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60126000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 02:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60155000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 03:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60182000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 04:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60207000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 05:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60233000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60260000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 07:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60287000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60310000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 09:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60335000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 10:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('60499000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 11:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('60733000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 12:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('60965000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 13:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('61192000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 14:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('61420000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 15:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('61655000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 16:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('61882000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 17:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('62109000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62337000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 19:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62399000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 20:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('62426000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 21:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62450000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 22:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62479000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 23:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62513000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 00:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('62540000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62574000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 02:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62604000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 03:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62633000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 04:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62660000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 05:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62687000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62715000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 07:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62741000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62762000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 09:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('62785000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 10:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62812000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 11:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('63029000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 12:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('63261000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 13:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('63340000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 14:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('63376000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 15:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('63422000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 16:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('63457000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 17:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('63495000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('63720000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 19:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('63951000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 20:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('64172000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 21:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('64409000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 22:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64656000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 23:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64722000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 00:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64758000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 01:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('64789000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 02:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64815000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 03:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64840000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 04:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64866000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 05:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('64892000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64919000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 07:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('64943000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64967000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 09:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('65111000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 10:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('65339000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 11:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('65569000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 12:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('65809000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 13:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('66048000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 14:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('66282000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 15:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('66518000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 16:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('66747000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 17:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('66972000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('67206000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 19:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('67433000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 20:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('67664000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 21:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('67923000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 22:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68179000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 23:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68282000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 00:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68324000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68365000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 02:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('68404000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 03:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('68436000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 04:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('68461000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 05:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68487000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68513000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 07:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68541000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68576000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 09:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68719000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 10:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68946000')]
        ]
    };


    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

And as you can see, it shows up pretty well but when I have the same code in IE, it doesn't render. I saw some people saying that it may be caused by some commas but I can't find any.

I have opened this fiddle in IE and I have the same issue, it doesn't print the line :(.

Please help,

Thanks.

Comment: Which IE do you use, have you any errores in the console?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in IE and Date.parse http://jsfiddle.net/px6dmvnx/5/.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        lang: {
            loading: 'Loading...',
            months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
            weekdays: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
            shortMonths: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            exportButtonTitle: 'Export',
            printButtonTitle: 'Print',
            rangeSelectorFrom: 'From',
            rangeSelectorTo: 'To',
            rangeSelectorZoom: 'Zoom',
            downloadPNG: 'Download PNG',
            downloadJPEG: 'Download JPEG',
            downloadPDF: 'Download PDF',
            downloadSVG: 'Download SVG',
            resetZoom: 'Reset',
            resetZoomTitle: 'Reset',
            thousandsSep: '',
            decimalPoint: ','
        },
        chart: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: true,
            plotBorderWidth: 1
        }
    });

    var options = {};
    options.series = [];
    options.xAxis = [];
    options.yAxis = [];
    options.chart = {
        zoomType: 'x',
        renderTo: 'graph',
        marginRight: 50,
        marginBottom: 50
    };
    options.title = {
        text: 'My Graph',
        x: -20 //center
    };
    options.subtitle = {
        text: 'Test',
        x: -20
    };
    options.legend = {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -10,
        y: 18,
        borderWidth: 0
    };
    options.tooltip = {
        shared: false,
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 1
    }


    options.xAxis[0] = {
        type: 'datetime',
        tickWidth: 1,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        gridLineColor: '#cdcdcd',
        tickPixelInterval: 70,
        opposite: false
    };
    options.yAxis[0] = {
        tickWidth: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        gridLineColor: '#cdcdcd',
        tickPixelInterval: 100,
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value;
            },
            style: {
                color: '#0080c0'
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'test2',
            style: {
                color: '#0080c0'
            }
        },
        opposite: false
    };
    options.series[0] = {
        name: 'test',
        color: '#0080c0',
        xAxis: 0,
        yAxis: 0,
        type: 'spline',
        data: [
            [123, parseFloat('42186000')] /*,
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 02:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42186000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 03:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42213000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 04:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42243000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 05:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42269000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 06:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42297000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 07:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42323000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42346000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 09:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42374000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 10:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42404000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 11:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42439000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 12:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42539000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 13:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42585000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 14:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42626000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 15:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42672000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 16:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42707000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 17:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42733000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42755000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 19:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42779000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 20:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42802000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 21:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42832000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 22:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42871000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-07 23:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('42916000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 00:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42952000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('42988000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 02:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('43015000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 03:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('43041000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 04:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('43069000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 05:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('43096000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('43124000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 07:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('43149000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 08:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('43176000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 09:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('43321000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 10:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('43552000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 11:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('43783000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 12:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('44014000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 13:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('44248000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 14:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('44479000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 15:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('44710000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 16:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('44939000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 17:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('45168000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('45398000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 19:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('45630000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 20:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('45863000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 21:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('46099000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 22:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('46353000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-08 23:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('46464000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 00:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('46516000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('46560000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 02:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('46592000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 03:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('46620000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 04:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('46647000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 05:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('46674000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('46701000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 07:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('46726000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 08:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('46765000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 09:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('46889000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 10:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('47122000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 11:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('47366000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 12:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('47625000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 13:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('47880000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 14:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('48123000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 15:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('48377000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 16:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('48621000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 17:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('48862000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('49087000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 19:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('49324000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 20:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('49555000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 21:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('49792000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 22:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('50038000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-09 23:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50145000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 00:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50186000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50222000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 02:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50250000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 03:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50275000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 04:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50302000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 05:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50326000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50355000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 07:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50380000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50406000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 09:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50544000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 10:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('50774000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 11:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('51002000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 12:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('51232000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 13:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('51466000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 14:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('51546000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 15:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('51587000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 16:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('51642000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 17:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('51780000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('52038000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 19:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('52292000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 20:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('52529000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 21:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('52772000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 22:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53016000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-10 23:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53078000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 00:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53114000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53148000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 02:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53176000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 03:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53203000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 04:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('53229000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 05:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53255000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53283000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 07:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53309000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53342000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 09:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53486000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 10:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('53714000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 11:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('53944000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 12:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('54173000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 13:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('54403000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 14:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('54633000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 15:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('54863000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 16:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('55094000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 17:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('55323000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 18:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('55553000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 19:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('55782000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 20:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('56018000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 21:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56265000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 22:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56522000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-11 23:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56635000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 00:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('56685000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56729000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 02:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56766000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 03:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56799000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 04:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56833000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 05:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('56866000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56902000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 07:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56935000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('56964000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 09:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('57107000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 10:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('57337000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 11:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('57581000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 12:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('57824000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 13:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('58063000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 14:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('58308000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 15:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('58547000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 16:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('58787000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 17:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('59020000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('59247000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 19:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('59491000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 20:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('59744000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 21:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('59825000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 22:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('59902000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-12 23:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('59984000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 00:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60063000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60126000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 02:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60155000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 03:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60182000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 04:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60207000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 05:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60233000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60260000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 07:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60287000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60310000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 09:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('60335000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 10:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('60499000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 11:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('60733000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 12:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('60965000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 13:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('61192000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 14:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('61420000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 15:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('61655000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 16:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('61882000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 17:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('62109000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62337000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 19:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62399000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 20:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('62426000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 21:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62450000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 22:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62479000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-13 23:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62513000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 00:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('62540000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62574000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 02:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62604000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 03:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62633000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 04:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62660000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 05:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62687000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62715000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 07:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62741000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62762000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 09:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('62785000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 10:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('62812000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 11:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('63029000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 12:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('63261000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 13:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('63340000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 14:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('63376000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 15:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('63422000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 16:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('63457000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 17:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('63495000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('63720000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 19:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('63951000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 20:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('64172000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 21:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('64409000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 22:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64656000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-14 23:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64722000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 00:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64758000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 01:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('64789000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 02:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64815000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 03:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64840000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 04:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64866000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 05:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('64892000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64919000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 07:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('64943000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('64967000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 09:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('65111000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 10:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('65339000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 11:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('65569000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 12:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('65809000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 13:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('66048000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 14:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('66282000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 15:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('66518000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 16:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('66747000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 17:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('66972000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 18:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('67206000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 19:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('67433000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 20:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('67664000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 21:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('67923000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 22:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68179000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-15 23:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68282000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 00:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68324000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 01:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68365000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 02:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('68404000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 03:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('68436000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 04:00:03 UTC'), parseFloat('68461000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 05:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68487000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 06:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68513000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 07:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68541000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 08:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68576000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 09:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68719000')],
            [Date.parse('2014-09-16 10:00:02 UTC'), parseFloat('68946000')]*/
        ]
    };


    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

You could try other data parsers.

EDIT: You can split your data and use [Date.UTC()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp) or prepare javascript timestamps in the backend.